# use jquery to replace the source of an image

Tags: jquery

I have one main image and a few thumbnails.  What I am trying to accomplish is when hovering over a thumbnail image, the main image source is replaced by the thumbnail's source.  Here is the code I have now:

HTML

```
<figure class="single__cover">
    <img src="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/CPML10248064.jpg" alt="" class="mainImg" />    
</figure>

<div class="single__gallery">

    <div class="grid-1 single__thumb">
        <a href="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/kitchen1.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]">
        <img src="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/kitchen1-260x180.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-1 single__thumb">
        <a href="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dinningroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]">
        <img src="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dinningroom-260x180.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-1 single__thumb">
        <a href="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/livingroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]">
        <img src="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/livingroom-260x180.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-1 single__thumb">
        <a href="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bedroom.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]">
        <img src="http://205.234.236.84/~garmanbu/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/bedroom-260x180.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" />
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mainImg').each(function() {
        $(this).data("original", this.src);                
    });
    jQuery('.single__gallery a img').hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).closest('.single__main').find('.mainImg').attr("src", this.src);
    },function() {
        var $main = jQuery(this).closest('.single__main').find('.mainImg');
        $main.attr("src", $main.data("original"));
    });
});
</script>
```

So far I am able to replace the main(large) image with the source of the thumbnail when hovering over the thumbnail.

What I want to do is have the main image keep the source of the thumbnail image and not have it change back to the original image source when you mouse out of the thumbnail image.

Also, my thumbnails are surrounded by an a tag.  Is there a way to use the href of the a tag instead of using the source from the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use `mouseenter` instead of `hover`. For the second question, use `(this).closest('a')` to get the containing `a`, then get its `href`.

```
jQuery('.single__gallery a img').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.single__main').find('mainImg').attr('src', jQuery(this).closest('a').attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You're answer was very helpful!  I got it working how I need it to

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to store the state in the data object.  Just get a handle on the original img srce then chain together mouseenter/mouseout.  Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h65Xse0wTpLf9KWKCO5P?p=preview) for an example

Comment: he doesn't want to restore the original image at all.